# Vuetify buttons not vertically alligned

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue and Vuetify. My question is about aligning buttons.
I have a container that contains a couple of v-text-fields and v-combobox they are centered in the middle of the container.

Now I want to have three buttons below this form, but whatever I try to do they are not aligned vertically, every button appears lower than the others. How can I correct this such that they are nicely aligned on the top?

[image: Buttons not aligned on the top]

```js
<template>
  <div class="ladder">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="higher_price"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.number]"
            label="Higher Price"
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="lower_price"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.number]"
            label="Lower Price"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row align="start">
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-col align="center" xs="4" >
          <v-btn color="primary"></v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-col align="center" xs="4" >
          <v-btn color="primary"></v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-col align="center" xs="4" >
          <v-btn color="primary"></v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-col>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two **v-col** which are not valid in the template you created, removing those will solve your issue..
Try this..

```
<v-row align="start">
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-col align="center" xs="4" >
      <v-btn color="primary"></v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col align="center" xs="4" >
      <v-btn color="primary"></v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col align="center" xs="4">
      <v-btn color="primary"></v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  </v-row>
```